# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found. address conflicts with other shared libs

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Turns out the address problem described below was OK. So frustrated T T

========================================================

Turns out it has nothing to do with downloading v7 so. And also I found when crashes happened, it loaded another shared library in the exact same address. why did this happened? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
08-26 21:10:24.640 D/dalvikvm(13686): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.xxx/mylib/libcodec_v7.so 0x41d3d748
08-26 21:10:24.875 D/dalvikvm(13686): Added shared lib /data/data/com.xxx/mylib/libcodec_v7.so 0x41d3d748
08-26 21:10:24.875 D/dalvikvm(13686): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.xxx/mylib/libcodec_v7.so 0x41d3d748, skipping init
08-26 21:10:24.890 D/dalvikvm(13686): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.xxx-1/lib/libfont.so 0x41d3d748
08-26 21:10:24.937 D/dalvikvm(13686): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.xxx-1/lib/libfont.so 0x41d3d748
08-26 21:10:24.937 W/dalvikvm(13686): No implementation found for native Lcom/xxx/xxxCodecWrapper;.decode:(I[B[BII)I
08-26 21:10:24.937 W/dalvikvm(13686): threadid=66: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41720700)
```

====================belows are old descripiton============================

My app has a built in "a_v5.so" and will automatically download "a_v7.so" under wifi. Loading "a_v7.so" if it exists using System.load.
All works fine except about 0.1% users crashed with "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found". And only crashed once.

here are some key codes:

```
1. download finished thread
    String tempPath = getTempPath();
    if (null != tempPath && !tempPath.equals("")) {
        deleteDirectory(tempPath);
        File dir = new File(tempPath);
        if (dir.mkdir()) {
            FileUtils.uncompressZip(zipPath, tempPath);
            synchronized (SOME) {
                if (!alreadyUsingV7) {
                    deleteDirectory(dstPath);
                    FileUtils.rename(tempPath, dstPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
2. loading thread
    synchronized(SOME) {
        boolean soFileExist = new File(libPath).exists();
        if (soFileExist) {
            try {
                // load v7
                System.load(libPath);
            } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                // load v5
                SoLoadUtil.loadSoByName(ctx, libName);
            }
        } else {
            // load v5
            SoLoadUtil.loadSoByName(ctx, libName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: forgot to memtion that only phones with cpu architect armv7&armv8 will download and use this armv7 so

Comment: I found that I miss used jobject and jclass, I guess that's the reason.